# How to send GCM notifications to iOS app from multiple servers?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, plist

My iOS app receives GCM notifications from one server. To do so, I had to create a plist file (GoogleService-Info.plist) and insert it in the project.

Now I want to send notifications to this iOS app from an additional server. The problem is that I cannot have two plist files in the project as I cannot rename them.

¿Does anybody know how to configure this scenario?

Comment: There's no indication in the documentation that you can have 2 GCM servers connected to the same project. That may be a limitation or a control by Google. Why need 2 origin points and not just make 1 a middleware to be sent by the original GCM server?

Comment: Yes, the middleware scenario is an option, but it is not desirable when the servers are from different parties. It looks more like a specific iOS limitation rather than a control by Google. What I am saying can be done in Android without a problem.